# org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg with TimeBasedRollingPolicy

Tags: apache-karaf, pax

I need to write Apache Karaf logging using in built pax logging to have it in TimeBasedRollingPolicy with daily rolling.

As the code is hidden, I can only overwrite the properties to utilize *TimeBasedRollingPolicy*.

Q1) Is TimeBasedRollingPolicy supported in Apache Karaf 4.2.9?
Q2) If yes, can anyone share the sample cfg file with TimeBasedRollingPolicy and associated properties to be used?

I don't want SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, just TimeBasedRollingPolicy. And I have to handle this through code.

org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg appears like this:

```
`# Rolling file appender
log4j2.appender.rolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
log4j2.appender.rolling.fileName = [path]/karaf.log
log4j2.appender.rolling.filePattern = [path]/app-name-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log
# uncomment to not force a disk flush
#log4j2.appender.rolling.immediateFlush = false
log4j2.appender.rolling.append = true
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 16MB

# Audit file appender
log4j2.appender.audit.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.appender.audit.name = AuditRollingFile
log4j2.appender.audit.fileName = [path]/security.log
log4j2.appender.audit.filePattern = [path]/security.log.%i
log4j2.appender.audit.append = true
log4j2.appender.audit.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.audit.layout.pattern = %m%n
log4j2.appender.audit.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.audit.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.audit.policies.size.size = 8MB

# OSGi appender
log4j2.appender.osgi.type = PaxOsgi
log4j2.appender.osgi.name = PaxOsgi
log4j2.appender.osgi.filter = *
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
log4j2.appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = TRUE
log4j.appender.out.file = ${mkv.logsdir}/karaf.log`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - check [Log4j2 RolloverStrategies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies) - there's no such thing as `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` (the name is available in Logback).

There's however `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` and here's working configuration that rolls over every 15 second:

```
log4j2.appender.timerolling.type = RollingRandomAccessFile
log4j2.appender.timerolling.name = TimeRollingFile
log4j2.appender.timerolling.fileName = ${karaf.log}/time.log
log4j2.appender.timerolling.filePattern = ${karaf.log}/time.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}
log4j2.appender.timerolling.append = true
log4j2.appender.timerolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.timerolling.layout.pattern = ${log4j2.pattern}
log4j2.appender.timerolling.policies.type = Policies
log4j2.appender.timerolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j2.appender.timerolling.policies.time.interval = 15
```

The `interval=15` may be confusing, but (after reading the source) it means "roll over every 15 of the least unit specified in file pattern".
So if the pattern was `${karaf.log}/time.log.%d{yyyy-MM}` you'd have trigger every 15 months.

With the above setting and waiting a bit I have these files:

```
time.log
time.log.2023-02-24-09-43-48
time.log.2023-02-24-09-44-18
time.log.2023-02-24-09-44-34
```

Comment: Can I remove the size based rolling if time based rolling is in place? Or both should exist?

Comment: It's up to you - just remember that `log4j2.appender.timerolling.name = TimeRollingFile` defines a "name" which should then be referenced as an appender to some logger, like `log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.TimeRollingFile.ref = TimeRollingFile`

Comment: I was missing this ref. added and log files are getting generated correctly.